# iptables 1.8.2 (debian10) does not show packet count in default policy

Tags: iptables, firewall

iptables 1.8.2 (debian10) does not show packet count in default policy?

In debian9 shows counters usually

In debian10, output command `iptables -nvL` is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
```

Comment: Can you show your complete rule set? Are you sure your traffic does not hit any defined rule and so not reaching the default action?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug report for this issue affecting Iptables 1.8.2 @ Debian 10.6

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=961117

My workaround for this is:

It does not make any difference if you load iptables rules during boot or later as root after the system is loaded (the policy counters always remain zero).
However, if prior to loading rules, you reset iptables using bellow commands:

```
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t filter -X
iptables -t filter -Z
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t nat -Z
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -t mangle -Z
```

then your policy counters start woking;

Right now I've added these rules at the begining of my iptables rules file and all is woking as it should.

Comment: this working for me! thanks!
 I add -Z option in my rules!

Answer (score 1):

Packet counters in the chain policy are only updated when you actually have packets to which the policy applies. Or in other words, when there are packets that enter a chain and which are not (dis-) allowed by any of the rules in a chain.

When all packets are matched by the rules in a chain (or there are no rules at all) the policy counters will remain on zero.

Arguably a good firewall configuration is one where the actual rule set determines the fate of the traffic and you never need to fallback to the chain policy to (dis-) allow traffic.

So in that regard it is bad firewall design that you have systems where the counters are NOT zero....

---

```
iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  1012 7864 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 7 packets, 968 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

In this case all traffic is matched by an explicit rule and default ACCEPT policy on the INPUT chain is never needed. The ACCEPT policy counters remain on zero

---

```
iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 1996 packets, 87824 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1386  101K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    4   176 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 31 packets, 4332 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

In this example the rules only open up the SSH and HTTP ports and rely on the INPUT chains policy to DROP all other traffic. The DROP policy counters will increase with every bit of traffic that is not allowed by the rules on ports 22 and 80 that allow SSH and HTTP.

---

```
iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1876  144K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    4   176 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
  115  9804 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

The same effective firewall as in the previous example, allowing traffic on ports 22 and 80 but with an explicit rule rejecting all other traffic, rather than relying on the default DROP policy. The DROP policy counters will remain on zero.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you wrote!

This is a web server listening on ssh on port 1891 and web on ports 80 and 443

If I run these rules below as a test, I have ssh access, but I don't have web access, and the counters don't work!

```
    Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   94  6188 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1891

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

That is ... the logic works, but does not count in the default policy drop

The same rules in debian9 count normally, I'm guessing it's a bug regarding the standard debian10 nftables firewall, what do you think?